# Copy of a constant?

Tags: c++, constants

```
Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial& p);
//Adds existing Polynomial to p, returning the result
```

So because we can't change the value of a const, is there a way to make a copy of this p to allow me to access the functions of p?

Sorry guys at work and quite display the entire program, but in Poly.H in the private field it reads:
private:
List < Term > poly

So in PolyTest.cpp

If I need two polynomials
p_add = poly1 + poly2

I need to write the function in the operator+ to add like terms. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I'm unsure why you need a copy of `p` instead of simply using it directly.  If you need to change `p`, then why not just change your `operator+` to accept `Polynomial p`? At any rate, if you need a copy of `p` for some weird reason, inside the body of the operator, then just make one: `Polynomial pCopy(p);` or, if you're using C++11: `auto pCopy(p)`.

Comment: I read the question 4 times and I still dont know what you want to achieve.
What has the const specifier to do with accessing a member function?

Comment: @Chris The p is a constant and I can't access the functions tied to it. So if I understand it correctly, you can make a copy which will allow you to access those functions.

Comment: @Bryan You should be able to use any of the functions that only read from `p`, you can't use any of the functions that would modify `p`.

Comment: @Bryan you _can_ access functions that are marked as `const`. Obviously, you can't access functions that aren't, since `p` is a `const` reference. Generally, if a member function doesn't modify the state of the object, you should mark it as `const`.

Comment: I would say that there are missing `const` in the methods...

Comment: If you make your `Polynomial` _const correct_ you won't need it to be changeable to access its functions. You may start with changing `+` signature to `Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial& p) const`

Comment: Just make it `const  Polynomial& operator + (const Polynomial& p) { return p; }`

Comment: @Bryan Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading so you can make an idea of how to properly implement the most typical overloaded operators.

Comment: @vsoftco Thank you much.

Comment: @DieterLücking `operator+` returning a reference? Weird.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to make a copy then just copy it in the function

```
Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial& p);
{
    Polynomial copy = p;
    // do stuff
}
```

Now just because `p` is `const` doesn't mean you cannot use its members/functions.  A typical `operator+` would look like

```
Something operator + (const Something& s);
{
    return Something(this->some_memeber + s.some_memeber,
        this->another_memeber + s.another_memeber);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a copy inside `operator+`, the most straightforward way of doing it is to pass `p` by (`const`) value:

```
Polynomial operator+ (Polynomial p);
```

Now `p` is a copy of the object you passed in that you can mess up with inside `operator+`. Of course if you pass by `const` value like

```
Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial p);
```

then the copy itself will be `const`, so you will be able to access only its `const` member functions.

As mentioned in the comments, sometimes passing by `const` reference and making sure that you only access the `const` member function is what you actually need, since you avoid the additional copy. However there are situations when a copy is necessary (most likely not here), such as when implementing the famous [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/3093378), in which case passing the object by value is the way to go, and the least verbose way of achieving the desired effect.

Comment: "there are situations when a copy is necessary" Most definitely not here.  Addition just should should not modify sum components

Comment: I think the only drawback from passing by value is that if the value is returned, RVO is inhibited.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hmm, I didn't know that. Do you know what is the reason?  I would have though that NRVO kicks in also.

Comment: @vsoftco I think it is just hard/impossible to implement.

Comment: @juanchopanza What I actually meant was the following: is there any difference from doing RVO on `p` and doing NRVO on a locally defined `pcopy`? I thought the latter is optimized out.

Comment: As long as `pcopy` isn't the function parameter and has the right type, RVO can kick in. NRVO to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it, you’re missing a `const` specifier on some member functions of `Polynomial`, e.g., you might have:

```
// Can modify *this.
std::vector<double> coefficients() { … }
```

When you need:

```
// Cannot modify *this.
std::vector<double> coefficients() const { … }
```

Adding the `const` specifier changes the type of `this` within the member function from `Polynomial*` to `const Polynomial*`. On a `const` reference, you can only invoke `const` member functions. (You can still invoke `const` member functions on a non-`const` reference.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You are probably referring to the const specifier at the end of a member function like so:

```
class Test
    // cannot modify members of Test
    void test() const;
    // can modify members of Test
    void test2();
};
```

You can only call methods declared as const at the end when operating on a const object.

If you need to modify a member inside a const member function (which is not often the case) you can declare it as `mutable`

The const specifier in front of Polynomial& p means it is a const reference to a Polynomial and hence you cannot modify the value of p.
I has nothing to do with accessing functions. If the method is declared in your class you can ofc access all methods from the same class.

You can however make a simple copy to mess around with the copy but not the reference to the input paramter:

```
Polynominal p2(p);
```

or

```
Polynominal p3 = p;
```

Comment: using `const_cast` to remove `const` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I would just remove the whole thing as not using it defeats the purpose of doing it.

Comment: @NathanOliver only if the initial object passed as reference was a `const`. If the object was non-`const`, then passing by `const` reference and removing `const` via a `const_cast` should be ok. But in any case, casts should be avoided as much as possible, and in this case you're right, `const_cast` is not the way to go.